# ¿Cómo hacer carga masiva de datos de forma rápida?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

Tengo cientos y cientos de ficheros .CSV, alguno de ellos llegan a pesar 1, 2, 3GB y otros apenas pesan unos pocos KB o MG, estoy usando un RDS de Postgres y otro de MySQL y PHP como lenguaje de programación para cargalos.

He probado muchas técnicas como **concatenarlos todos en un único fichero por tabla** y funcionaba bien, excepto en algunas tablas que los ficheros pesaban 40 y 70 GB.

Ahora estoy probado exactamente lo opuesto, es decir, dividir los ficheros CSV en máximo 500.000 líneas y cargalos de esa forma.

A través de este código lo que hago es que, al momento de dividir los ficheros, que los nuevos contengan el header. Lo he puesto en 500.000 líneas aunque desconozco si es un parámetro óptimo, en su lugar me hubiese gustado indicar un peso exacto por fichero .CSV ya que, Amazon menciona algo de esto aunque no sé cómo hacerlo.

```
awk -v l=500000 '(NR==1){header=$0;next}
                (NR%l==2) {
                   close(file);
                   file=sprintf("%s.%0.1d.csv",FILENAME,++c)
                   sub(/csv[.]/,"",file)
                   print header > file
                }
                {print > file}' $1
```

He leído la siguiente información oficial de amazon a través del siguiente [enlace](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/improve-performance-of-your-bulk-data-import-to-amazon-rds-for-mysql/) que menciona que el peso ideal sería 500 mb (aunque más abajo menciona 100-250 MB, **no me queda claro**, aunque está claro que no es ideal tener ficheros csv de 1GB).

¿Alguna técnica o parámetro óptimo para dividir los CSV en partes óptimas que alguien me pueda recomendar? ¿Cargarlos de forma paralela?

Comment: Creo que falta información contextual. ¿Dónde se generan los datos que guardas en esos ficheros? ¿No sería mejor, en esa fuente, programar algo que vaya enviando esos datos directamente a la base de datos, controlando los tiempos, algo así como un Cron cada N horas por ejemplo?

Comment: Comienza por [`acá`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK). Aunque concuerdo que es mejor una estrategia de replicación o sincronización.

Comment: Me parece que ya te sugerí alguna vez que calcules el tiempo de transmisión para que veas en dónde estás parado.

Comment: Gracias por poner contexto, Sal.  No tengo acceso a eso, digamos que llega de un proveedor externo. Yo obtengo muchos CSV y simplemente debo cargarlos en una base de datos.

Comment: Load Data IN FILE

Comment: Para estimar el tiempo de transmisión basta con papel y lápiz -y un poco de voluntad-, no necesitas ningún acceso. Es el inicio del camino correcto, es un proceso, no un evento.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo utilizar "LOAD DATA INFILE" en las cargas masivas de archivos tipo csv con esta sentencia lo haces directo.

Por otro lado si estas en un entorno linux puedes dividir el archivo por cantidad de registros con un solo comando.

Este por ejemplo te va a dividir el archivo csv por cada 500 mil registros y cada uno de los archivos te va a colocar una letra del alfabeto

```bash
split -l 500000 archivo.csv archivo_parte_
```

Luego de dividirlo o no, utiliza este codigo SQL para cargar un archivo csv en BD, le indica que tu separador es una coma que cada linea termina con un ENTER y que ignore la primera lina por si trabajas con titulos o encabezados:

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE 'archivo_parte_a.csv'
INTO TABLE Tu_tabla
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

**IMPORTANTE**: La tabla debe tener los mismos campos en ese orden en que lo tiene el archivo.

Tu proceso lo puedes automatizar con esos codigos utilizando php, desde estar pendiente que en una carpeta exista el csv hasta la carga, eso si, lo importante de todo es que esos csv mantengan la misma estructura, sino tendrias que hacer unpaso previo de depuracion.

Comment: Sí, es lo que tengo actualmente hecho, aunque no uso "split" porque lo que hago es "copiar" el header en cada uno de los ficheros csv generados. 50mil no es el valor óptimo, de hecho es lo que estoy intentando encontrar. Si utilizo 50mil filas por fichero csv me tarda 31h, si uso 10mil me tarda 28h y si uso 1mil me tarda 44h. Seguiré probando diferentes valores